# Optimizing stills in Adobe Premiere CS4 using h.264 mainconcept?

Tags: video, adobe, adobe-premiere

When .mp4 video gets out (656x369px), it looks perfect, only .psd scenes (stills/ images) looks quite distorted. Not anti-aliased shortly.

That includes still drawings in video clips also.

Adobe Encoder is not giving me an option to optimize stills (steady images) before exporting via this awesome codec.

This issue is automatically taken care off well ONLY when exporting pure HD video (like 720p) without clicking anything.

Any ideas how to tweak this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found solution (if anyone asks for the same thing)..

It happens when you select to develop PAL video at the bare start when creating project, but you are actually using images created in square pixels (1.0), what is actually NTSC standard display.

Creating new project as NTSC display (and again setting to custom resolution with 1.0 square pixels display) fixed this issue.

Now scenes with images are crystal clear when video is created at the end.